# How to make Vim buffer switching by name autocompletion to match only filenames and not paths?

Tags: vim

I have two text files as shown in the dir structure below.

```
├── abc_base_xyz.txt
└── base
    └── def.txt
```

After opening these two files in buffer, when I type `:b base<Tab>`, the autocompletion completes the path to def.txt as it contains "base" in its path, but it doesn't match abc_base_xyz.txt at all. I want it to match abc_base_xyz.txt also.

I tried `:b *base<Tab>` and it works. Is there a better way or setting to match filenames instead of path?

I have the below line in my vimrc.

`set wildchar=<Tab> wildmenu wildmode=full`